# Why cant i require SQLite3 in preload.js?

Tags: javascript, electron, electron-builder

This is my preload.js file in electron application

```
window.onload = () => {
  
  const $ = require('jquery');
  //const sqlite3 = require('sqlite3').verbose();
  //const db = new sqlite3.Database(':memory:');
  



  var form_div="";
  document.querySelector("#ppage_btn").addEventListener("click"()={
      
      //console.log("ppage_btn renderer file");
      $('#form-div input').each(function() {
          $(this).attr('value', $(this).val());
      });


      form_div = $("#form-div").clone();
      var elements = document.getElementsByClassName("cats");
      while(elements.length > 0){
          elements[0].parentNode.removeChild(elements[0]);
      }

      var divToPrint = document.getElementById("form-div");
      
      var db_data =  divToPrint.outerHTML;
      db.serialize(function() {
          db.run("CREATE TABLE invoices (codeblock TEXT)");
          var stmt = db.prepare("INSERT INTO invoices VALUES (?)");
          stmt.run(db_data);
          stmt.finalize();
      });

      newWin= window.open("");
      newWin.document.write(divToPrint.outerHTML);
      newWin.print();
      newWin.close();
  });
}
```

Whenever i un-comment these lines
//const sqlite3 = require('sqlite3').verbose();
//const db = new sqlite3.Database(':memory:');
and click on #ppage_btn button to save and print the form ,no error shows and the whole app window crushes ..
is there any proper way to add sqlite3 in preload.js file ?

Comment: What error do you get?

Comment: Need more information than "app crashes"  Take note here: https://www.w3resource.com/node.js/nodejs-sqlite.php << "We assume that you have already installed SQLite3 and node.js on Windows or Linux environment."

Comment: i have edited my question, please check now

Comment: @sam707 is sqlite3 installed on your server? Can we check the server error logs for additional info?

Comment: Do you have `nodeIntegration` set to `true` or `false` in your window creation? The default setting is `false`. Your render process will not have access to Node.js methods such as `require` by default. That is why you are receiving a console error. You would be best to move all your database operations into the main process and use [IPC](https://www.electronjs.org/docs/latest/tutorial/ipc) to transmit data and actions between processes. Doing so will also prevent your render process from possible freezing during database calls.